# Lispy code? Palindrome of product

Tags: beginner, programming-challenge, lisp, common-lisp

My answer to [Project Euler problem 4](https://projecteuler.net/problem=4) (largest palindrome of product of two 3-digit numbers) is below.
Please suggest improvements, style changes, indentation, commenting, naming, ...

And nitpicks are welcome!

Other than general *stuff* about the code below, I'd like to ask specifically about

1. `assert` is good to use? Frowned upon? Has possible drawbacks?
2. `progn` looks like a 2nd class construct. Is the usage in the final function correct? Are there other (more Lispy-like) options?

```
(defun e004-digits (n &optional (base 10))
    "return a list with the digits of n"
    (assert (and (integerp n) (>= n 1)
                 (integerp base) (>= base 2)))
    (loop with remainder
          while (> n 0)
          do (setf (values n remainder) (floor n base))
          collect remainder))

(defun e004-palindrome6p (n6)
    "determine if the 6-digit number n6 is a palindrome (in base 10)"
    (assert (and (integerp n6) (>= n6 100000) (<= n6 999999)))
    (let ((dd (e004-digits n6)))
         (and (= (nth 2 dd) (nth 3 dd))
              (= (nth 1 dd) (nth 4 dd))
              (= (nth 0 dd) (nth 5 dd)))))

(defun e004-largest-palindrome-in-square (siz)
    "find maximum palindrome product"
    (do* ((a siz)
          (b siz)
          (nextb)
          (sum (+ siz siz))
          (p (* a b) (* a b)))
         ((e004-palindrome6p p) p)
       ;; following half diagonals ensures (proof needed?)
       ;; the first palindrome product found is the largest
       (setf a (+ a 1))
       (setf b (- b 1))
       (if (> a siz) ; start next diagonal
           (progn (setf (values a nextb) (floor sum 2))
                  (setf b (+ a nextb -1))
                  (setf sum (- sum 1))))))

(defun e004 ()
    (e004-largest-palindrome-in-square 999))
```

<sup>code also available on [github](https://github.com/pm62eg/)</sup>

Comment: `progn` usage in last function is correct and needed as `if`'s then clause must be a single expression. Note however that `setf` can take multiple pairs of places and values like `(setf x y a b)` so you could do that *instead* of using `progn`

Comment: I'd personally consider changing the `(if <condition> (progn ...))` to `(when <condition> ...)`. It feels as if it flows a bit better.